# ANY operator with jOOQ

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I am having troubles understanding the following. I have a field and some values:

```
Field<T> field = ...;
List<T> values = ...;
```

Now, I want to express the filter `field = ANY({... the values ....})` in a `WHERE` clause. PostgreSQL supports this `ANY(array of values)` operator. I got this idea from https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/30/sql-in-predicate-with-in-list-or-with-array-which-is-faster/.

I tried the following to create a condition:

```
field.equal(PostgresDSL.any(PostgresDSL.array(values)));
```

The above doesn't work. This compiles:

```
field.equal((QuantifiedSelect) PostgresDSL.any(PostgresDSL.array(values)));
```

**First question**: Why is this additional cast necessary? Should the API be altered? I am not sure on which side (mine vs. jOOQ's) the generics error actually is.

However, after this change, the query itself is not working. It gives the error:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.util.ArrayList is not supported in dialect DEFAULT
```

**Second question**: How do I declare/create an array of values? The call `PostgresDSL.array(...)` above is falling back to `DSL.array(...)`, which is probably root of the second problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DSL.any(T[])`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any-T...-):

```java
// Using varargs
field.equal(DSL.any(1, 2, 3));

// Using an actual array
Integer array = { 1, 2, 3 };
field.equal(DSL.any(array));
```

Your mistakes are:

1. [`PostgresDSL.array(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/util/postgres/PostgresDSL.html#array-org.jooq.Select-) corresponds to PostgreSQL's `ARRAY(<SELECT expression>)` syntax, which is useful when you want to collect the results of a correlated subquery into an array. You don't need that in your case, because if that's what you wanted, here, you could simply use [`Field.in(Select)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#in-org.jooq.Select-). Note, there is no `DSL.array(...)`
2. You referenced the [`DSL.any(T[])`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any-T...-) operator from `PostgresDSL`, which is a subclass of `DSL`. This works because Java allows it, but might have contributed to the confusion here.

Comment: I tried it out and I am getting another problem which I also encountered yesterday. Now, I have: `field.equal(DSL.any((T[]) values.stream().toArray()))`. The following SQL is generated `id = any (?::any[])`. However, that parameter is never bound and we end up with a SQL syntax exception. That was the reason why I tried doing `DSL.any(DSL.array(...))` as stated in my original question.

Comment: I tried it out and I am getting another problem which I also encountered yesterday. Now, I have: `field.equal(DSL.any((T[]) values.stream().toArray()))`. The following SQL is generated `id = any (?::any[])`. However, that parameter is never bound and we end up with a SQL syntax exception. That was the reason why I tried doing `DSL.any(DSL.array(...))` as stated in my original question. But as said, I did that wrong. I will try that again.

Comment: I got it working with `DSL.any(DSL.array((T[]) values.stream().toArray()))`! Great succes :). The only thing left that bothers me is the manual convert to array instead of just passing a `List<T>`.

Comment: You have many questions which would be worth asking in a new question, I think... :) In particular, you shouldn't cast to `(T[])`...

Comment: I know that I should not, but the API is not accepting `Object[]...` but `T[]...`, so it needs that type. I'll create some questions then, as there is another thing that started to puzzle me :).

Comment: Q1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856153/are-arrays-optimized-in-jooq-postgresql :)

Comment: Q2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858042/jooq-fieldt-dsl-anydsl-valt :) Thanks a lot.