# Are arrays optimized in jOOQ & PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have a large list of identifiers which I would like to add to the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
identifier IN (..., ..., ..., ...)
```

However, that is pretty slow, because it has to bind each value individually. Remember, the list is pretty long (almost 1000 values). In such case, it is better to use:

```
identifier = ANY({..., ..., ..., ...})
```

Now, we are only binding the array, just once.

I tried doing that in jOOQ:

```
Integer[] values = {..., ..., ..., ...}
DSL.any(DSL.array(values))
```

The following SQL is generated:

```
"identifier" = any (array[?, ?, ?, ...])
TRACE | 2017-08-24 10:02:08,914 | JooqLogger.java | 187 | Binding variable 1       : ...
TRACE | 2017-08-24 10:02:08,947 | JooqLogger.java | 187 | Binding variable 2       : ...
TRACE | 2017-08-24 10:02:08,958 | JooqLogger.java | 187 | Binding variable 3       : ...
...
```

So, this makes me conclude that we are still binding each value separately? Is there a way to optimize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```java
DSL.any(DSL.array(values));
```

With:

```java
DSL.any(values);
```

To create a single bind variable.

Alternatively, you could create that bind variable explicitly:

```java
Field<Integer[]> array = DSL.val(values);
DSL.any(array);
```

Comment: When using `DSL(values)` the following SQL is generated: `identifier  = any (?::any[]))`. This parameter is never bound and we end up with a SQL syntax exception: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "any"`.

Comment: `DSL.any(DSL.val(values))` gives exactly the same problem.

Comment: I am using version 3.9.5. I just run the query like any regular select query: `context.select(...)...fetch()`. On the `DefaultConfiguration`, the Postgres dialect is set. I could write a GIST, but take would be for early next week.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with an `Integer[]`. Are you using an `Object[]` perhaps? Or do you have inconsistent varargs parameter types? Indeed, will need a full code snippet then, to see how you run the query.

Comment: Oh I see. The problem is explained in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45858042/521799. Indeed, you're using `Object[]`. Will answer there.

Comment: OK! I did not realize they were correlated. Let's tackle that one first. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, this was related to the other ticket. My initial question is also resolved here: there is indeed just one binding, for the whole array. Thanks!