# jOOQ Field<T> = DSL.any(DSL.val(T...))

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

This question is a spin-off from [ANY operator with jOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835065/any-operator-with-jooq) and [Are arrays optimized in jOOQ & PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856153/are-arrays-optimized-in-jooq-postgresql#45857633).

I have a `Field<T> field` and `List<T> values` and I want to express SQL `identifier = any({... the values ...})`. I tried doing:

```
field.equal(DSL.any(DSL.val(values.stream().toArray())))
```

(Note this is part of a generic implementation, so I don't have the actual types at this point. I only have `Field<T>` and `List<T>`.)

But this doesn't work, since the API accepts `T...` instead of `Object...` and `field.equal(DSL.any(...))` needs that `T`. So, I changed this to:

```
field.equal(DSL.any(DSL.val((T[]) values.stream().toArray())))
```

However, in comments is said that I should not do this. Probably a dumb question and Java instead of jOOQ question, but how should it be done?

Side question: isn't it a good idea to simply accept a `List<T>` in the API? This might also improve performance, since we are avoiding the manual array creation.

Note: The same situation holds for `field.equal(DSL.any(values.stream().toArray()))` and `field.equal(DSL.any(DSL.array(values.stream().toArray())))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you're using the jOOQ API with an unsafe cast, you should wonder: Am I using it right?

In your case the mistake is here:

```java
DSL.val((T[]) values.stream().toArray())
```

The correct way to construct this array is (assuming `T` is `Integer`, here):

```java
DSL.val(values.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new))
```

Or, if `values` is a `Collection`, then more simply:

```java
DSL.val(values.toArray(new Integer[0]))
```

It is important that you pass an array of the correct type to jOOQ as jOOQ will use reflection on that array to figure out what data type it is, and then map it to e.g. PostgreSQL `?::int[]`

> Side question: isn't it a good idea to simply accept a `List<T>` in the API? This might also improve performance, since we are avoiding the manual array creation.

The problem is that Java erases the generic type information of `T`, which jOOQ needs to correctly cast bind variables in various edge case situations. So, `T[]` is a much more preferrable type than `List<T>` in such cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem is, I only have `T` here. I don't have `Integer`, `String`, ... The code from my original question is from 'a generic framework', hence the `T`. So I am struggling to get this construction working with generic types. Basically, I have `Field<T>` and `List<T>`. Any idea how to progress from there?

Comment: I guess this will boil down to: I need an instance of `T.class`, so I can create `T[]` and progress from there. Or do you see something else?

Comment: Pseudo code: `T.class == Field<T>.getType()` And `T[].class == Field<T>.getDataType().getArrayType()`

Comment: Great! This is working now: `field.equal(DSL.any(values.stream().toArray((s) -> field.getDataType().getArrayType().cast(Array.newInstance(field.getDataType().getArrayType().getComponentType(), size)))))`. Thank you!

Comment: @BasOpers: Note you can also provide an alternative answer to your own question, hinting at how you ended up doing it. Perhaps that will be useful for a future reader of this question!